# Angularjs overwrite object in localstorage

Tags: angularjs

i have a list in ng-repeat. And there is a button near the every item in the ng-repeat. When i click the button object id stored into the localstorage correctly. But if i click another one localstorage change to new object id. Is there any way to save object ids into localstorage like array?

I add object into localstorage with this code

```
localStorage.setItem("mac_id_local", JSON.stringify(mac_id));
```

I am using this in a function already. And i must do it in if else statement. If response is 1 value must stored in localstorage. If response is 0 value must deleted from localstorage.

```
if ($scope.response == 1) {
   $scope.veriler[index].isFavori = true;
   localStorage.setItem("mac_id_local", JSON.stringify(mac_id));
}
else if ($scope.response == 0) {
  $scope.veriler[index].isFavori = false;
  delete localStorage.mac_id_local;
}
```

I just wanna make array in localstorage like this => mac_id_local = "131, 154, 185, 195"

I hope i can tell me problem correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array variable and add items to it and add it to storage,

```
$scope.ids= [];
$scope.ids.push(mac_id);
localStorage.setItem("ids", JSON.stringify($scope.ids));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.items=[];
$scope.items.push(mac_id);    
if ($scope.response == 1) {
  $scope.veriler[index].isFavori = true;
// storing our array as a string
localStorage.setItem("mac_id_local", JSON.stringify($scope.items));
}
 else if ($scope.response == 0) {
  $scope.veriler[index].isFavori = false;
delete localStorage.mac_id_local;
}

// retrieving our data and converting it back into an array
var retrievedData = localStorage.getItem("mac_id_local");
var movies2 = JSON.parse(mac_id_local);
```

Comment: please tell me if i am wrong. I am using Json.stringify already.

Comment: I'm sorry I did not understand you

Answer (score 0):

localstorage stores key value pairs, while storing data into an localstorage object, you should use `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` while accessing it.

You can use this factory:

```
.factory('$localstorage', ['$window', function($window) {
  return {
    setObject: function(key, value) {
      $window.localStorage[key] = JSON.stringify(value);
    },
    getObject: function(key) {
      return JSON.parse($window.localStorage[key] || '{}');
    },
  }
}])
```

Also, keep in mind, you'll have to set an entire object (not just a particular key) while using this factory, on each setObject call.